How to recover RAID 6 from IBM DS3512
We have an IBM DS3512 storage enclosure with RAID 6 on IBM servers.
Two hard drives failed.
During maintenance, the wrong hard drive was replaced. When the server started, it recognized that three hard disks failed, and the RAID was destroyed.
The original disk was put back in, but the RAID  status has not changed.
Is there a way to restore this?
